# How to set Spotlight Search default input source?

Tags: macos, catalina, spotlight, input-source

I want to always use English language input source in Spotlight Search(<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>), when I was typing in a different language input source in a app, the Spotlight search will pop and with that language, I want to use English always.

I’m on macOS 10.15.7 and my system language is set only to English (US) primary.

How to do this?

Comment: Please edit in if your language has secondary or a different primary.